# Search a MongoDB from an AJAX call with NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, ajax, mongoose

I'm trying to do a search in a MongoDB database from an AJAX call.

The data is events with a start and end DateTime and a String description.

The issue I have is that the nodejs router doesn't seem to receive the criteria sent in the  ajax call.

Here's the code:

Mongoose model

```
const eventSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
   description: {
      type: String,
      require: true,
      default: ""
      },
   beginDate: {
      type: Date,
      required: true,
      default: Date.now
   },
   endDate: {
      type: Date,
      required: true,
      default: Date.now
   }
})
```

Ajax call

```
function showEvent(dateValue) {
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      var valResponse = JSON.parse(this.responseText)
      var eventStart = new Date(valResponse.beginDate)
      var eventEnd = new Date(valResponse.endDate)
      document.getElementById("eventFrom").innerHTML = datetimeToText(eventStart)
      document.getElementById("eventTo").innerHTML = datetimeToText(eventEnd)
      document.getElementById("eventDesc").innerHTML = valResponse.description
    }
  };

  xhttp.open("POST", "/getevent", true);
  xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json;");
  xhttp.send(JSON.stringify({ 'beginDate': { '$gte': '2019-05-23T00:00:00.000Z' }, 'endDate': { '$lte': '2019-05-23T23:59:59.000Z' } }))
}
```

NodeJS router

```
const express = require("express")
const router = new express.Router()

const Event = require("../models/eventsModel")

router.post("/getevent", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    Event.find(req.body).exec((err, result) => {
      res.status(200).send(result)
    })
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e)
    res.status(400).send(e)
  }
})

module.exports = router
```

Now if I add a console.log(req.body) in the router it only returns an empty JSON ( { } ).

Any help is welcome!

Comment: Sounds like you need to use express and bodyparser. Why aren't you even using express?

https://github.com/expressjs/express

Comment: I do use Express.  I edited the question and added the according code. Concerning bodyparser, I never used it before.  I'll have to look for its usage.

Comment: Actually, I'm finding that express now has bodyparser included with it. Before you had to install it. In your app, do 
app.use(express.urlencoded({extended: true}));

Answer (score 0):

This is a good example of how ridiculous mistakes can make you lose hours of coding!

There is two errors in the code that I posted:

1- On the line xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json;"); the semicolon inside the quote shouldn't be there. So the correct line is xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");

2- The data sent is not well formatted:
Instead of 'beginDate': { '$gte': '2019-05-23T00:00:00.000Z' } it must be beginDate: { gte: '2019-05-23T00:00:00.000Z' }

Having "beginDate" and "gte" inside quotes prevent nodejs to process them as identifiers. Same thing for the $ in front of gte. With these quotes, it is impossible to access the data with req.body.beginDate.

Hope the infos will help other peoples...